# jQuery tabs load 404 page

Tags: jquery, tabs, jquery-ui-tabs

I am using jQuery Tabs for my project, with "lazy" loading tab content via Ajax.

But, when I do a typo and Rails framework gives me HTTP 404 with error page, Tab will not load the page and I can't see the error information. (**Correction:** Rails seems to return HTTP 500, when there is a typo in the code)

Is there a way to tell jQuery to load/display pages returned with 404 code like normal?

I've got this far:

```
$('#tabs').tabs({
    ajaxOptions: {
        error: function (xhr, status, err) {
            // Call success function - but how?
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Why would you call the success function on error?

Comment: I want to see the error information returned by Rails. I want it only during development. I will turn it off in production.

Comment: @PetrCezar See my comment below--you shouldn't need any JS code to do this, so the 500 error vs the 404 shouldn't be an issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ajaxOptions object takes the same options as the actual jQuery .ajax() method, so you can use the statusCode object to your advantage here http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

The example on that page for the statusCode looks like this:

```
$.ajax({
  statusCode: {
    404: function() {
      alert('page not found');
    }
  }
});
```

To use it in the jQuery Tabs context, just pass statusCode as an object into the ajaxOptions like this:

```
$('#tabs').tabs({
  ajaxOptions: {
    statusCode: {
      404: function() {
        //your 404 handling code runs here
      } 
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you, it's a big move forward. But I still cannot find what line of code will load the returned page to the tab.

Comment: Ah! If that's your goal, just use Chrome's Developer Tools to do this.  Click on the Network tab in Developer Tools, then look for the request made by your ajax call when you click on a tab. Any data returned will be in the Response section that appears when you highlight that particular request on the left. Here's a screenshot: http://grab.by/bdKo You can also see what the page would look like (i.e. your default 404 page with the errors in it) by clicking on Preview: http://grab.by/bdKs

Answer (score 1):

404 page also fire success event not the error event. try inside success event